# using value of a column as an alias to another column in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I have the below query and result structure in Typeorm .

```
await getConnection()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .from(Service,"service")
        .select('service.dueDate',"date")
        .addSelect('array_agg(service.id)',"services")
        .groupBy('service.dueDate')
        .getRawMany();
```

Sample Result :

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "date": "2021-04-17T07:24:32.833Z",
>         "services": [
>             1,
>             5,
>             4
>         ],
>     },
>     {
>         "date": "2021-04-27T12:55:20.879Z",
>         "services": [
>             6
>         ],
>     }
> ]
> ```

But i need my structure to be like :

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "2021-04-17T07:24:32.833Z": [
>             1,
>             5,
>             4
>         ],
>     },
>     {
>         "2021-04-27T12:55:20.879Z": [
>             6
>         ],
>     }
> ]
> ```

meaning that i should have value of column date to use as the alias for column services .

Comment: Simply apply `Array.prototype.map()` onto your resultset and redefine/reshape your objects.

Comment: @IVOGELOV that what im doing rn , but i want to see if there is a SQL way for it to compare performace.

Comment: I don't know how you can express this with `typeorm` but with raw SQL you can use JSON_AGG and JSON_BUILD_OBJECT functions.